# Trying to write a Generic Filter IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, iqueryable

I am trying to write a generic filter.
This filter is being used for nearly every table in my DB. I need a generic Equals filter so I can apply to all my tables without repeating my code everywhere

: I have the following code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilterModel<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, FilterDTO filterModel)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    if(filterModel.SelectedCompanyId != 0)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty("iCompanyId");
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Equals", new[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        source = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }

    return source;
}
```

`type.GetProperty("iCompanyId");` The `iCompanyId` will always be an `Int32`.

So when I am debugging and reach this line:

```
var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Equals", new[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
```

I get this Error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

I need to filter the Input IQueryable if `iCompanyId == filterModel.SelectedCompanyId`

This is how I am calling the filter:

```
telematicDevices.ApplyFilterModel(model.FilterDTO);
```

Where telematicDevices is an IQueryable from the DB (Entity Framework)

Answer (score 3):

Can you not apply a .Where statement?

```
//Interface we need to access property
public interface ICompanySpecific
{
    public int iCompanyId { get; }
}
```

For each object that has iCompanyId create a partial class to specifiy the interface.

```
public partial class Person : ICompanySpecific
{
    //No code is needed because Person already has the iCompanyId property
}
```

And now you can use this with Person or any type that implements ICompanySpecific

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilterModel<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, FilterDTO filterModel)
    : where T: ICompanySpecific
{
    return source.Where(o => o.iCompanyId == filterModel.SelectedCompanyId);
}
```

Comment: How? This filter is being used for nearly every table in my DB. I need a generic Equals filter so I can apply to all my tables without repeating my code everywhere

Comment: I added a code example with generic constraint for your baseclass.

Comment: But I don't know the <T>, It may be Cars, People, Employees anything. If I use 
    : where T: People I can't use it for Cars

Comment: Is there a baseclass or interface that contains iCompanyId?

Comment: No.iCompanyId is in nearly every table of my Database. The source I am passing through can be of any type of Table from the DB

Comment: @DawoodAwan Then create an interface with that property and have all of your types implement that interface.  Done.

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately certain EF workflows don't let you do this. Is your EF CodeFirst, DatabaseFirst, or ModelFirst?

Comment: In your workflow do you destroy/regenerate your models?

Comment: @psibernetic The use of `partial` classes will allow him to add to the generated classes (like, say, by adding an interface to be implemented) without risk of it being removed when the types are regenerated.

Comment: Also, the OP can simply use Code First with his existing database, which is really the better approach, anyways. EDMX deprecated and soon to be removed entirely in EF7.

Comment: Wow, good info @ChrisPratt, I hadn't heard that. May be worth getting a hold of https://efreversepoco.codeplex.com/ or is there going to a migration path officially supported?

Comment: I don't think there's really a migration path to be had. The classes generated by Database First should work just as well as Code First POCOs, I would think. So really, you just have to strip out the EDMX cruft and make some modifications to your context. I have an article that explains how to use Code First with an existing database: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Comment: Does this satisfy your need appropriately or do you need a dynamic expression tree solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilterModel<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, FilterDTO filterModel)
{
var type = typeof(T);

if(filterModel.SelectedCompanyId != 0)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(type, "type");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "iCompanyId");
    var constExp = Expression.Constant(filterModel.SelectedCompanyId, typeof(int)); // I'm assuming that SelectedCompanyId is an int.
    var equalExp = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, constExp);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, constExp);
    source = source.Provider.Where(lambda);
}

return source;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The expression that you're creating, if written out statically, would look something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilterModel<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    FilterDTO filterModel)
{
    return Queryable.Equals<T, int>(source, p => p.iCompanyId);
}
```

What you actually want to do is create the dynamic version of this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilterModel<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    FilterDTO filterModel)
{
    return Queryable.Where<T, int>(source, 
        p => p.iCompanyId == filterModel.SelectedCompanyId);
}
```

1. You need to have your lambda actually compare the property that you have to `filterModel.SelectedCompanyId`.  This would mean using `Expression.Equals` passing in both the projected property and a constant representing the value to compare it with.
2. Use `Where` instead of `Equals` for the `Expression.Call` call.  (Or, for that matter, just calling `Where` as a method, instead of building an expression representing that call, because it will represent itself as an expression through its implementation.)

And that's assuming you don't want to make your life easy and just [write out the implementation statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28570768/1159478) which is not only much easier, but also allows for static typing.